# mySQL logic: output of table join not correct

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am trying to query two tables: finished_events and flagged_events. 1st of all I need everything related to the company_id so

```
  SELECT *
  FROM finished_events
  WHERE company_id=$id
  ORDER by schedule, timestamp
```

I then changed this to:

```
SELECT * FROM finished_events 
INNER JOIN flagged_events 
      ON finished_events.company_id=flagged_events.company_id 
WHERE finished_events.company_id=$id
ORDER by finished_events.schedule, finished_events.timestamp
```

I have tried using FULL JOIN, LEFT JOIN, and RIGHT JOINs all unsuccessful. Specifically what I want is to get is a combined effort of the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM finished_events
        WHERE company_id=$id
        ORDER by schedule, time_stamp";

$flagged_sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM flagged_events 
                WHERE company_id=$id 
                ORDER by schedule, time_stamp";
```

The tables are a bit different so UNION won't work here. I can post dummy database entries but this won't be of too much help as I need all from both tables. The 2 links between the tables would be the company_id and the schedule columns. Essentially what is going on behind the scenes is timestamps being put into a different table to which I then process either into finished_events or flagged_events. Flagged events will need the user to do something about it until it is a finished event. So this script is generating the data for the GUI, hence why I need to query both tables and create an associative array of customer details then an array of events (from these 2 tables). So creating the assoc_array is no problem I just need to get this query to spit out all the events and order them correctly. Let me know if you need anything specific to solve this one, thanks :)

EDIT
SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4c30/1
this almost fixes it but not quite right, it repeats entries at the bottom

Comment: You could create an SQLFiddle demo, so we could test something.

Comment: It DOES *seem* like you want UNION. Just have NULLS where columns don't match up.

Comment: and if I need what the data in the columns that don't match up? :) I've started a SQLFiddle demo btw :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this may be useful for you:

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
  SELECT *, 'finished' as event_type FROM finished_events
  UNION
  SELECT *, 'flagged' as event_type  FROM flagged_events) a
ORDER BY a.schedule, a.time_stamp
```